# Adding char which is a math operator to random string

Tags: c++, string, char, addition

I am trying to add "+", "-", "*" etc. to a string but it doesn't work.

Lets say I have string "12 3 +" Then I use `string tmp` to get values between spaces like "12" "3" "+". my `cout` prints "12" and "3", but "+" is missing

```
int ONP() {

    string wyrazenie;
    getline(cin, wyrazenie);

    string tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < wyrazenie.length(); ++i) {

        if (!isspace(wyrazenie[i])) {
            tmp += wyrazenie[i];

        } else {
            cout << tmp << endl;
            SOME CODE.....
            tmp.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with your post so that potential answerers can identify and diagnose the problem you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that `+` is your last character, so you won't go in else block for it.

`std::cout` `temp` after the loop would show your missing character:

[Demo](https://ideone.com/AYCMGG)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, I see an issue that would cause the last character to not be printed. This is because you are only printing `tmp` when the next character is a space. So "12 3 +" would print "12", "3". Then `tmp` contains the value "+" since its never printed nor cleared, but is never printed. If your input string is "12 3 + " (notice the space) the '+' char would be printed too.

This can be solved with printing and clearing `tmp` after the loop is done if `tmp` still contains any data.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never display the last token of the string unless the string ends in a space.  When you have `"12 3 +"` you read in the `12` see a space, print the `12` and clear the string.  You do the same thing for `3`.  Then you get `+` but since that is the last character in the string you never run the `else` part of the if statement to print it out. You can fix this a few ways.  You can check if `temp` is not empty after the loop and if it is not then handle that.  You can rework your logic in the loop to handle when you are on the last character and it is not a space. You could add a space to the end of the input so it will end with a space and the loop works as is.